# Set RabbitMQ message properties with Apache Camel

Tags: java, rabbitmq, apache-camel

I am using **ProducerTemplate** to publish messages to RabbitMQ. It only allows me to send body and headers. RabbitMQ allows to pass additional ***Properties*** with the messages. However, I don't see an option to do that with the **ProducerTemplate**. ***Properties*** are special headers and RabbitMQ only allows a few valid properties to be passed.

This is required as the consumer of the message is expecting certain information to be passed as Properties instead of headers and we won't be able to modify the consumer code.

The RabbitMQ Java Client has the below method. I am looking for an equivalent with Camel.

```
public interface Channel extends ShutdownNotifier, AutoCloseable {

// other methods in the interface
void basicPublish(String exchange, String routingKey, BasicProperties props, byte[] body) throws IOException;

}
```

Comment: What version of Camel are you using? You should generally just use camel message headers for that which there is API in producer template to use

Comment: In Camel, every message header will be automatically turned into a JMS property (with same name) when target endpoint is of type jms. I guess the same principle is true in case of rabitmq endpoint ? So just send a body with a header "foo" and check if you have a "foo" property in RabitMq